How to use AMD hardware acceleration VAAPI when using ffmpeg in qtcreator?
ffmpeg version:4.2.2
env:QT creator
I passed this command in terminal:
ffmpeg -hwaccel vaapi -vaapi_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -i input.mp4 -vf format=yuv420p,hwupload -c:v h264_vaapi -b:v 1000k output.mp4

This can be accelerated, the CPU usage is very low
But when I want to use code to implement hardware accelerated encoding, it prompts:
cannot allocate memory(-12)

my c++ code:
av_hwdevice_ctx_create = (&hw_device_ctx,AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_VAAPI,"/dev/dri/renderD128");

print:-12
I can be sure that I compiled ffmpeg correctly because I can enable vaapi hardware acceleration through the command and my graphics card has enough video memory.
Possible causes:
I introduced -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale in my qt pro file libs, but did not add -lva -lva-drm
Is it correct to add -lva -lva-drm after libs?
What should I do?
